# Give counterexample: Vector w can be written as a unique combination of $v_1,v_2,v_3$ provided w$\in$Span($v_1,v_2,v_3$)

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, vectors

I previously had to prove the statement, and I did so by showing there were scalars a and b that were equal to each other but now I have to give a counterexample. I just proved this hypothesis' correctness, did I prove it wrong or is there a proper counterexample?

For reference, I proved the hypothesis like this:
Given vector w $\in$ Span($v_1, v_2, v_3$), we have $a_1v_1 + a_2v_2 + a_3v_3$ = w and $b_1v_1 + b_2v_2 + b_3c_3$ = w
With some basic algebra, we can reach the point where $a_1-b_1=a_2-b_2=a_3-b_3=0$

Comment: Your argument holds only if $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent. If they are not, they it is easy to construct a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathbb R^2$, let $v_j = (j,0)$ for $j \in \{1,2,3\}$. Then $w = (1,0)$ is in the span of $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and
$$w = 1v_1+0v_2+0v_3 = 0v_1+\tfrac12v_2+0v_3 = 0v_1+0v_2+\tfrac13v_3.$$

Answer (score 0):

No, as noted in the comments and the other answer, you made a mistake.  The last step of your proof requires linear independence.

This is always false when the vectors are linearly dependent.

For instance, $\{(1,0),(0,1),(1,1)\}$.  Then $(1,1)=1\cdot(1,0)+1\cdot(0,1)+0\cdot(1,1)$ and $(1,1)=0\cdot (1,0)+0\cdot (0,1)+1\cdot (1,1)$.